# Installing a package installs only the package with version number attached

Tags: python, setuptools, python-packaging, pyproject.toml

I migrated my setup.py to pyproject.toml for my package but now when I try to install my package via pip, it only install the package version with the version attached.
Ex: package is `aanalytics2`
and the folder created in my Lib > site-packages folder is : `aanalytics2-0.3.4.dist-info`

Therefore, when I try to do `import aanalytics2`, it cannot find the package.

Here is my config file for the pyproject.toml.

```
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools", "setuptools-scm"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[project]
name = "aanalytics2"
authors = [
    {name = "Julien Piccini", email = "piccini.julien@gmail.com"},
]
description = "Adobe Analytics API 2.0 and 1.4 python wrapper"
readme = "README.md"
requires-python = ">=3.7"
keywords = ["adobe", "analytics", "API", "python"]
license = {text = "Apache License 2.0"}
classifiers = [
    "Intended Audience :: Developers",
    "License :: OSI Approved :: GNU General Public License v3 (GPLv3)",
    "Operating System :: OS Independent",
    "Programming Language :: Python",
    "Topic :: Scientific/Engineering :: Information Analysis",
    "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.6",
    "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.7",
    "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.8",
    "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.9",
    "Development Status :: 4 - Beta"
]
dependencies = [
    'pandas>=0.25.3',
    'pathlib2',
    'pathlib',
    'requests',
    'PyJWT[crypto]',
    'PyJWT',
    "dicttoxml",
    "pytest",
    "openpyxl>2.6.0"
]
dynamic = ["version"]

[project.urls]
homepage = "https://github.com/pitchmuc/adobe-analytics-api-2.0"
changelog = "https://github.com/pitchmuc/adobe-analytics-api-2.0/blob/master/docs/releases.md"

[tool.setuptools]
include-package-data = true

[tool.setuptools.packages.find]
where = ["aanalytics2"]
[tool.setuptools.package-data]
mypkg = ["*.pickle"]

[project.optional-dependencies]
dynamic = ["version"]
```

Is there anything I am missing ?
I read the documentation and the "name" keyword is the one to be used no ?

my project structure is:

```
./
./aanalytics2/.git/
./aanalytics2/aanalytics2/
./aanalytics2/aanalytics2/__init__.py
./aanalytics2/aanalytics2/__version__.py
./aanalytics2/aanalytics2/aanalytics2.py
./aanalytics2/aanalytics2/aanalytics14.py
./aanalytics2/aanalytics2/config.py
./aanalytics2/aanalytics2/configs.py
./aanalytics2/aanalytics2/supported_tags.pickle
./aanalytics2/aanalytics2/otherPickleOrPyfiles
./aanalytics2/dist/
./aanalytics2/docs/... (md file)
./aanalytics2/test
./aanalytics2/.gitignore
./aanalytics2/LICENSE
./aanalytics2/MANIFEST.in
./aanalytics2/pyproject.toml
./aanalytics2/LICENSE
./aanalytics2/README.md
./aanalytics2/requirements.txt
./aanalytics2/setup.cfg
./aanalytics2/setup.py
```

Documentation I read:
https://python-poetry.org/docs/pyproject/
https://peps.python.org/pep-0621/

Comment: Yes, I do have subfolder that is called aanalytics2 that contains all of my python files + some pickle files that contains table that I load as online documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setuptools default discovery behavior is searching for a unique subdirectory alongside the `pyproject.toml` with an `__init__.py` in it. By configuring it to look *inside* the `aanalytics2` subdirectory it is not able to find any packages.

Just remove these lines from `pyproject.toml`, and let it use the default discovery:

```
[tool.setuptools.packages.find]
where = ["aanalytics2"]
```